# Commits from another project appear in my project's graph

Tags: git, github

What does it mean when my git graph shows disconnected commits like in this screenshot?

[image: Weird git graph]

To make matters more bizarre, the commits in the lower half of the screenshot do not belong to my project. Looking at the source of these commits I can see that they are from an open source project that I contribute to but they are from before I got involved in that open source project.

Did I manage, somehow, to get source code from the other project into my own project?

Any tips on how to clean up this mess?

My project is on [github](https://github.com/Jericho/StrongGrid) and you can see the "undesired" commits [here](https://github.com/Jericho/StrongGrid/commits/2.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a shell, you can run

```
git tag | grep -v 'v' | xargs git tag --delete
```

to remove all the tags in the old project that keep the branch alive. Then, just run

```
git gc
```

to garbage collect the inaccessible commits.

Similar steps should be taken on the remote, too. I'm not sure how to run gc in Github, but to delete the tags, you can run

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

Comment: thanks. I manually deleted the tags and ran `git gc` and I no longer see the unwanted commits.

Comment: @desautelsj - You won't see them in default output, but they might still be there because reflogs might be keeping them alive.  If you can find the commit ID for one of the commits, you can try checking out with that commit ID to see if the commit is really still there.  I would also guess you'll still need to clean up the remote.

Answer (score 1):

At its core, git is a "content addressable file system"; the source control commands are built on top of that.  My point being, it's more flexible than you might expect about what it can contain.

In this instance, it's hard to tell 100% for sure from just that screenshot, but it sounds like you have two commit graphs in your repo.  That's fine with git, and sometimes useful.  (They even have an option you can use on `checkout` specifically to start a new commit graph - `--orphan` - and an option on `merge` to bring two graphs together - `--allow-unrelated-histories`.)

So, do you have the other project's code?  Sure sounds like it.  How did it get there?  I don't know, but you could've fetched it from the other repo, or someone else could've pushed it into your origin and you picked it up on a subsequent fetch.

How to clean it up?  Well, you can start by deleting any branches and/or tags that point to the unwanted commits.  Then git will eventually, hopefully, clear out the commits themselves.  If you need to force a faster cleanup, you can do so locally with `git gc` (though you may have to wipe out some reflogs first).  On the server, it depends on what level of access to housekeeping / gc functionality are provided by the hosting software (github in this case; I'm not too familiar with that end of things).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I manually deleted the tags and forced the cleanup by running `git rc` and I no longer see the unwanted code.